# Refutation in first order logic

Tags: satisfiability, first-order-logic

Consider the following statement

> In FOL, we can reduce entailment checking to satisfiability checking:
>
> $S \models  S' \iff S  \land \neg S'$ is satisfiable (This proof
>   strategy is called refutation).

Is the above statement true? If yes, then I got confusion because of the following steps

$ S \models  S' \iff S\implies S'$ is true

$S \models S' \iff \neg S \lor S'$ is satisfiable

$S \models S' \iff \neg( S \land \neg S') $ is satisfiable

$S \models S' \iff  S \land \neg S' $ is unsatisfiable

Which one is true?

Comment: This is a math question, and belongs in [math.se].

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I disagree. Logic is fundamental to CS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a typo in your source, and your derivation looks correct. So the corrected statement should be:

> $S \models  S' \iff S \land \neg S'$ is **un**satisfiable

or

> $S \models  S' \iff {\boldsymbol \neg} (S \land \neg S')$ is satisfiable